# Can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64' of Gaussian

Tags: python

Here is my code in python.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import scipy
import scipy.special as spec
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.integrate import quad

plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [16, 12]
plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 8})
yt = [0, 0.38745412097864285, -1.002269868159093, -2.314564000385705, -4.802857358026568, -1.5019732144521891, 1.4688884316226247, 1.727614248747603, 3.088674358621797, 3.2096568151591653, 1.3493610497073807, 2.445844943072014, -5.736758906495692, 2.218712137590721, -2.709220619930857, 1.0942799072361316, 3.4096461782868297, -7.538277206888424, 0.052984441752835135, 2.926245721841296, 4.011959253768955, 9.002357111249339, 2.5940650040036446, -1.5296969682372543, -6.972190489703499, 7.236368309434913, -7.380403471576314, 0.774899674308226, -1.7035146353622346, 3.2160023344644757, -1.9266964118914824, -3.5672794331080127, -5.300245192584367, -2.380077354440279, -6.086330955507553, 4.696045582124042, 5.814161149142599, 2.3193905823859207, 3.57722747584176, -1.6832357347875906, 2.9517365725044713, 0.5911306281513161, -1.3458134815994671, 0.1837294299634267, 0.18535714794489935, -3.8713936779247837, 1.974413491713314, -11.306028534459038, 2.8504880820746044, -2.5958993904223675, 1.914355052065572, -3.3313536579561, -2.4956102955162223, 0.47361487339913494, -1.6515592656197853, -1.0629497746768755, 5.616451940618738, 6.944697429506685, 1.8702964258377164, 0.01281289357890869, 3.649964848940479, 5.61317065207995, -2.953691170509018, 2.884797226834413, -1.044660262277648, 0.35515165033077994, -1.7677942072302801, -8.096716468491616, -4.719012410613325, -0.29100443889696287, -2.6740154470029642, 3.6440403027289587, -9.216799249810553, -5.185790986767708, -0.15217167871889667, -1.1880576396674951, 1.911238632403507, 4.272081334982359, 2.8351077093397743, -1.58580362949557, -3.269262951563836, 3.036799597614841, 0.08642751592524366, -2.475526295472673, -0.679049575975087, 0.44799576742830655, -5.060070311538365, 5.665525298552657, -4.026538915348719, 3.3146992259558434, -0.4177608545022089, 3.766515528070085, -1.6884145950499476, 3.24667810361219, 0.9050966912349367, -0.5913558866668879, -7.169764012555738, 2.234947613287756, -2.6218557616792033, -5.450546708101444, 1.9916273424057735, -3.95387549205815, 0.5496377438860791, -4.2342041980447584, 2.5157488518088167, -3.3100395514453336, 0.1899236146474435, -2.6712942249665033, 5.06978593980379, -1.0117910987524736, -4.1175229302403356, -0.38414281863586797, 6.515661696271817, 7.577501733554006, 0.668858428682779, -3.1809237146029505, -1.6368392837910537, 6.242550274294498, -2.2983122361952275, -3.473848792682792, -2.8362430034422914, -3.8152604706208604, 3.678219919532748, 5.151220808247991, 2.855792766582435, 2.544749312402906, -0.8498845897066453, -7.2225681000428725, 1.760749206067019, -1.1465280678462535, 2.5473330738319704, 5.972275191604391, -4.541952680757053, -1.5328577392321823, -2.239735735871928, 3.072833826878303, -3.9654816140487137, 4.963822797640927, 3.501442849657843, 2.8567978497669118, -2.4756047017175757, -1.924711142811062, -3.9272211965545507, 2.7035219479713883, -1.211664666612532, -1.358420533067804, 0.760086648293119, -3.931404065425583, 3.5423213955291604, -1.201102278712106, -0.9397542485875189, -7.13310864723869, -1.2891765568658822, 8.662641162914346, -4.396227018661884, 4.581418898444012, -3.2225315486224138, 2.2535690710400775, 1.3006592073514711, -1.7717969794352917, 2.3542296716350726, -4.033592112604773, 3.7260656080015258, 10.831981313197803, 1.4298625560725626, -0.8258351733588616, -0.9571225964535462, -2.749035488510787, 1.8503628121101618, -0.7959524571055555, 5.763171477624923, -5.299603714082399, 3.6996857568980164, 1.0456120414378616, -6.40401274910291, -1.473265463006205, 2.411700466490456, -2.3611305565581824, -3.535748941195129, -1.331576063323314, 6.876002855379311, 1.4253088707904567, 2.282241762650488, -4.397544523607304, 7.53600680460438, -5.139148189658129, 0.24095179398804176, 1.2732649102835427, -0.9344284165910629, 3.8275913461073228, 2.4816351563067, -6.026938589673475, 2.468920057265757, 2.506796923603812, -5.30995151117078, 3.2717047673616095, 0.027127470828635508, -2.965565105821613, -1.1196932886057607, -6.658748558755029, -1.0746163919154852, 7.6751608274459056, 0.6243960551336966, -1.28839381024285, -8.98201619953395, 2.202270351591344, 5.458096336039061, -3.839267108841071, -2.282900356688063, -3.2162478662716754, -8.547448978436142, -0.4560463700948365, -3.4415872351501355, 1.1343786359070829, -4.010208972331833, -0.0752445417224177, 6.0284238054342705, -4.588879679748267, 6.516688447794113, 7.684433521778439, -3.4704691714406404, -3.2877940537990984, -4.365577977865888, 2.408351071056065, -6.220864439577192, 1.0968839738062215, 12.42375892458833, -1.3670605431551863, -0.2707411747700323, -7.545292917774447, 1.802557245852908, -1.7947206184465163, 1.7848870504175138, 0.029979356531816735, 3.2209558371153983, -2.256368027764397, 7.341574292274447, 4.607689897343437, -5.741636764784179, 3.4642969172047047, 0.88749939928371, -4.455059663342198, -3.9926499041639336, -3.6671339415564264, 5.203601111204823, -9.155438248287899, -0.6564472402783071, -1.1817243312871422, -1.1848359022633603, -2.875181515343533, -1.4304221052209043, 2.011857691254695, -2.1806679771180715, -4.47958455382719, -1.5624236160410454, -0.8980690344537191, -7.73450765258646, 5.361134753709152, -1.0094175571505486, 2.7481717136386448, 0.3501930956517791, -0.5603640278767963, 7.013931359237862, 6.081575623541313, 5.899845480191744, -0.02820344681261785, -0.4401525022066656, -0.8098434809363004, 3.0314739652482694, -3.3479219169122545, 0.22485842789020002, 5.645424813023987, -13.488466156828052, -1.9621792641074878, -3.916207711138781, 1.9528524715751803, -0.4104882460727337, -5.878472797983287, -1.5089315525866358, 0.42029646277431365, -4.3842230465960395, -0.38967048446959074, 5.420422577150274, -5.5163598597955295, 1.5867376259839225, -0.17841018918737092, 2.534176042481485, -1.6462782272133853, 2.127580426915715, 4.553309814827096, 5.94169937716703, 1.5717486283078654, -4.014627617960092, -2.112512191062236, 0.10144030327285836, -6.551217717727237, -3.7890274094080967, -3.000516178378396, 2.0407446341146076, -4.704171702011276, -0.979730703730331, 1.6888416154720562, 5.727056695059232, -6.053443732112711, 0.9641637888077658, 7.907378281178104, 2.583119789601263, -2.0120212008397833, 1.6061341175503594, 3.2651442459331776, -2.6408160009919786, 6.979390697227772, -4.093573130658885, -1.6991570663551874, 3.6229450417505196, 1.163101430761257, -5.178828000399178, -6.188318570789282, -2.264294710495536, 1.1103201896250443, 0.8154619536063682, -3.3369444907524892, -5.498921599700261, 3.159302741615666, -3.1872500594818285, -0.7731872032124572, 0.06069852030157342, -9.229844446785139, -6.358752611446657, -3.597770903196511, 3.270447550569555, 6.497773693297295, 0.8875728299308161, 10.343252655666275, 8.823693686619105, 3.119798400299216, -3.392059729939152, 1.5929542437481745, -5.748718637159586, 7.438474373444294, -2.972209752016766, -0.24725683149401836, -1.049820264172072, 1.0108818036966647, -4.098083829612011, 4.564474987706147, -2.151378718123818, -1.385937527780414, 7.6543802047659435, 3.689644436274813, 6.059263672502358, 3.0516940999916686, 4.902000731271145, -1.3642311057812495, 6.0583383695187125, 5.847251032865058, -4.133476085747907, -0.08590087891247793, -6.685842732738066, -5.48497521455505, -0.4278055206134937, 9.923789331807528, 2.6823261604092585, 1.8367265880059902, 5.104009802769209, -1.5574161436736158, -1.6544365446294351, -3.8551721744005794, -4.546692608713239, -3.166532912503588, 1.009058842405624, -6.901696005846494, -0.37549967823320557, -3.5762403696375844, 9.051297772439057, 3.470150241869245, 0.7495623488870632, 1.570966952445719, 1.179888330218802, -9.412557261279192, 2.775117540189928, -5.5819260467442655, 1.0361189005264126, 0.13486932980772537, -0.10460456369906676, 3.4474555563906817, -3.0154296340328357, -1.4769250056139405, -1.4913116611638149, 1.6855186374303763, 4.041533909841557, -8.416121949922353, -3.0328736902289832, 0.921746977937799, -0.40248882921643564, -1.0518539599263985, 1.1719041101312169, 1.0747028645303762, -5.142654192359417, -3.5163237287658067, 2.9919839257525345, 4.46386300300681, -0.42978493703940407, 2.060605404294085, 1.8809489144073253, -0.22719113911347635, 1.4959658060936925, -2.3054418408948667, -0.20363734471277914, -1.1637717494154254, -5.19599281745098, 0.22955052510590226, 7.450174771989808, 4.9105453212232755, 1.489386230694732, 3.4064338309281594, 0.9080102378771336, -7.507156455319091, -3.9847560178076997, 1.1590910203465066, 7.869152704213092, 3.966649243238831, 4.934411147311495, 2.6499353729801145, 3.521384996946621, 1.598772193536172, -0.7574096616681597, -0.7553455623858599, -5.649238285935432, -2.7604813834245796, 3.1371748975806404, -8.340312877242946, -3.2984074852522327, -4.36462846029356, 1.1190520804550121, 5.300087447370759, -5.2811763653159085, 0.34740707808393173, 3.2186617248713083, 6.081121398149014, 3.8236041257127056, -1.2631977628152624, 3.9516554096717393, -0.7567307857381418, 2.818628460260108, -1.4144741968333863, -2.5737324385590488, -1.7948542872289803, 3.2142970517133946, -0.8481568299151909, -1.635738719598541, -4.393071679386803, 4.510972043152806, 0.3894774352531762, -2.3905776569066526, -2.7362104329003043, 6.046924776784018, 0.2528417736406619, -4.746225253037715, 3.633120044273075, 1.679816170549812, 2.3175264081996265, 3.2180498224827914, 3.603114122937908, -7.4936027480366825, 3.261086746813262, 5.095355720972123, -0.5424310663729138, -3.5382034037180388, 0.9383670253478024, 4.673053661963977, -1.029899987946221, 5.246987151766918, 2.469215851980271, 1.233761058759932, -0.10480405563264159, -5.828784515400375, -8.23534504288414, 3.09777523602205, -0.5873016543148841, -2.482576104397294, 2.9815787064036052, 1.0092853803029, -1.9399940942621008, 1.2956907565955766, 3.0200882121350787, -2.5402698553502447, 4.879611040579229, 1.92445576728443, 0.122812255625878, -6.955285402448948, 2.01389114720233, 0.5474409912581578, 3.3223426673141976, 4.925936786286283, -1.5369750845923296, -5.089543477723282, -1.2604593189958868, -1.2938974021320426, -3.5028209407941624, 2.5519252318041192, -0.9358189585047346, 2.4633872306743423, 3.685294351853683, 0.8030698001507295, -2.5780212518405787, -1.6711775822112998, 4.894917624121537, -1.12514187695385, 0.7102537775790382, 3.536270754867028, 5.89890881719617, 0.7736574526836096, 2.2987773112652046, 4.132255552491156, -0.07909390876339704, 7.684493357746495, 0.8539739413324127, 1.634169754087879, -2.0935542036148362, 1.5809573750429784, -2.56946721070226, -8.38083771939167, 4.497851455401913, 3.0817555458245827, 1.1242187235406391, -3.651483972810876, 2.6600763153223874, 4.422355711444818, 0.3243386764349489, 0.4558732293786662, 1.6502349072762084, 1.369664312747155, 2.0524693922586823, 6.005424096057131, 5.988855076740532, -3.274307368417524, -3.9720122984011232, 5.397275788901552, -6.702638743060951, 6.024447226453132, 4.318191210457048, -1.604569845785303, -10.394222055890197, -2.064501691262789, 3.6315991896569666, 1.2120342124677157, 1.1964104622261147, 1.7166758887447477, 1.037177898911692, 0.7106870983774081, -6.033086994112676, 1.036900525376171, 2.164883466900927, 0.7124404562543929, 4.57638782446324, 4.338085000191355, -2.9759461500633004, 3.985108676186353, 1.8012010529851272, -1.2605558627591706, -3.120602988006642, -2.238065732445528, 0.5796623991701801, 4.491693762610205, -4.657364242183711, 3.8470070178538287, 4.345867156947476, -0.31829293888274224, -7.7000507179220605, 0.06266586664266477, -2.7298932557121334, -1.7758646395505253, 1.9227805778014213, 0.9816580780177991, 0.049150188605945125, -1.0822018218149698, -0.5239735701193285, 1.9960307255930307, -1.0165341640738748, 3.958885848025956, 1.1020337877565312, -8.762559929574069, 0.00993200560807686, -0.7376566329416703, 1.0009561834284093, 0.9546834405199064, -1.7055969232741302, 2.011527942691301, -7.147196535428117, -2.402482449472744, -4.256518320026275, -3.02144712336069, -6.378000737045404, 3.862840814365326, 1.2679097314101104, 5.323151807904171, 2.5902180655257117, 0.6358002498324016, 6.142962554646713, -2.8847408352850725, 1.3120886702341634, 4.146140322772489, 3.347164730973886, -7.686749845885891, 3.6769745229733286, -4.982709726594961, -8.480528712438248, -1.450622067970716, -1.7924842252899236, -5.996723102093291, 1.383798542170528, 2.837899151150653, 2.218952536665189, 3.3416392792063587, -0.9479350336835349, -3.844692509826288, 3.2282279907849163, 6.590720082663785, 0.5607348950504352, -3.5443316081081333, 0.5700628937102666, 3.720031068921291, -5.1650078929573455, -5.4517337006694335, 4.415713870879441, -2.0871090603251026, 2.560249228995714, -8.50448813391101, -1.6909952991123045, 2.7253138174844067, -6.4413601613672995, 1.220319808203303, -4.006498033170413, -1.665723124283289, 2.110644920857536, -0.4793335227759791, -5.733216880402911, -3.630325560757307, 0.8434968410069785, 4.756025055183571, 0.5203215838347622, -5.76978857159433, -6.68037615138825, -2.031902468543236, 0.6515723825261125, -0.6116702307714772, 1.2363491236630157, -1.0576448221084358, 0.7791490503293778, -6.420344857757853, -7.035608871008858, 1.0942113600883778, -1.8441149357406061, 2.076248738554464, 0.17277427217757382, 4.47469697368981, -7.195084358451002, -9.72170172932336, -0.2839570425769985, 3.8851248535326692, 2.7439138427311156, 5.136519177660151, 2.506114016504188, -0.5828601655504597, 2.4029454139479376, 5.076189780266203, 6.346257257424208, -5.188285882010508, -4.912376980220734, -7.6386796476832926, -2.845894460527087, 3.649038659234987, 1.088330906372627, 2.7474474371236988, 2.5056903584242853, -3.464614042751859, 4.694461013321206, -0.1366201925154273, 3.6463795283364675, 7.549108569669622, -2.0878702706936787, 4.186808736429005, 4.404484957680959, -0.1179951369086101, 3.2313862286163664, -3.0698247727840893, 1.1753150296159616, 5.481227037571564, 1.764761811903554, -2.422366559042142, -1.2223968915241579, -0.7725194923232269, 4.324511742431088, 3.424818010272863, 5.108632677081562, 3.8445947234715887, -5.304028742209495, 11.222980347555106, 2.8114898714429084, 4.705693972523717, 5.85867130483502, -9.2498479506209, 3.211822336630103, 4.985303724984175, 6.750249980635796, 2.7710234090455694, 8.807550704034028, 0.7690872080405534, 1.5355221612541468, 0.6576583206758283, 4.04330091020494, -4.694881668333982, 2.302268490602129, 4.095870699634648, 0.39278994594318173, 1.2106504561813518, -1.7134807642359402, 2.450194844997368, -6.504350191926179, -2.097182615171389, 2.1822504147853765, 3.068554947478241, -3.680790422924922, 1.493372970778589, -1.286961388491297, 4.088720434683629, -1.0316350344394292, -1.006772578122669, 4.919196224749743, 1.6229444189790305, 1.610588097343941, -3.0973707793480103, -4.876516354933736, 0.5418758403625986, 2.315899071956606, 3.851946983480981, 2.9999719646329277, 3.1963238312793196, -4.553207907996405, 3.65287268830015, -0.9843492840367666, -0.7311219614625288, 0.37355147079354617, 1.3635093852319582, -0.5594792376671025, -1.5126529049905182, -1.2900419354534698, -1.6127892507077406, -3.2706055243251475, -0.6430467020239508, -0.3505199692993787, -5.662895214229093, -10.697613876799723, -4.566997273840869, 1.4132251640116726, 0.1951978123707229, 1.4900315963236264, 8.41857870398601, 7.796993090713268, -1.9857933164238888, 4.306505201941584, 2.8176626398419797, -4.1552081236223195, -5.917653544883206, 5.499803349052956, -2.2645744474768303, -6.798513239236024, -4.740652687439993, -1.2646698172531283, -1.9583898917772495, 6.627741515712118, 4.04675247944603, 4.089554774830436, 1.412397086628091, 1.6815788259159445, 3.9852416702452187, 3.2099476873641253, 2.0371028414974157, -2.9039329861358287, -3.2162502608429566, -0.23831563893488886, 0.4722688954052778, -3.3067516870730307, 6.031422355153236, -4.966034576553041, -7.898460814404585, -7.178133627735924, 7.730349255700381, 4.499820564171289, -3.69037541630284, -0.4832718432406114, 0.2678016697609267, 5.388325863863697, -3.671355553506417, 3.5614508258852395, 0.1316428760713046, 2.0610266965104773, -2.2677176804769443, -4.308572068620792, -0.1481794878907437, -0.40215579552857667, 2.060985038291904, 3.8210152973330764, -0.9194308001981218, -1.8128948560576221, -3.294529908600663, 2.918369622390004, 0.9664310545615604, 0.5317196771539221, -5.906738599167991, -2.5715368742066076, 4.184765297846017, 4.280485262766576, 4.0110037168411115, 4.346074752695239, 4.553131153872294, -0.704044156673793, 6.426899376798088, -2.820118768469844, -0.3554117286115163, -2.9053404814381794, 6.3268489543871915, -3.173509569304329, -3.0995850957333304, 3.5490425707540543, 7.345582396638509, 0.7271983573475961, 0.4178611041405357, 0.47930547343838736, 3.0652447395611437, -1.0298052515765974, 3.7470806069101137, 1.3088007130517292, -6.64169115616794, 0.843334121056715, 1.7698759392630077, -0.6015968804727002, -5.4324295706309105, 3.247423547407893, 1.9925337627659452, -1.7009635002327188, 4.974225477217179, 3.3442701302986793, -2.8571002335009688, 0.36585543438460383, 1.493301276061197, -0.8777435485728102, 8.139691487341281, 3.012021355714524, 3.869201031405985, -4.059937950191197, 0.5828772870533768, -2.64684502684046, -2.39629369134451, 0.29411782594865815, -3.2961857549097333, -1.0840839140064737, 1.1925181202539208, -0.6059126865338019, -5.845135561872333, 4.260907916536143, -4.724652394815867, -6.4521742138011104, 2.088122046776087, 2.557137242531929, -5.019626765769917, -2.640324472127482, 1.5584940763732746, 1.7896355632625858, -7.560696608927635, 1.8067444463296216, -0.18522854799276828, -6.95066867164271, 9.41551222086456, 2.009244930827858, 0.37646113593736313, -2.196922936527921, 0.5217285625801852, 2.248009504375808, 0.018338339521064492, -0.8985580898659377, -8.255551344370765, -0.7090012137899037, -3.4486579359261293, 1.9712132991565579, -1.8258122555999552, -2.4486542157005227, 0.26124786822931684, -0.6371496000163926, 3.9407179032702793, 5.177288163269365, 2.214421364155749, 2.596314099722268, -10.535509041194247, -4.068114973266398, 4.413744692667632, 3.591136979040117, -0.8293338368844223, -1.5102288594390494, 1.7440515423093625, -4.966292975293064, -3.9605331458336592, -6.977576800833758, -3.794903793491794, 2.6193946144434292, 1.8152429655389943, 4.857563218096395, 2.956119432048222, 3.4311344191892745, -4.551288836292315, -0.6408285909109968, -3.8230933152996283, 0.9752620379237547, 1.7604990814485488, 1.7064077689693202, 7.628844986160884, 5.776728874302797, -3.2227111957132637, 3.86893478386497, -1.6485850215021647, -2.716847859492231, 0.5643213574329026, -10.452555901224612, 3.9765542627024275, -2.404994319358997, 1.9658619712095957, 6.189054149421412, 4.427012113747337, -0.2849807645506912, 2.0310703372625927, 0.4361030527470229, -7.220227965536197, 3.0269419796080226, -4.684127462590129, 0.46351223984515894, -1.1898068762197747, 4.480993019071568, -3.717018027805752, 5.009794807314046, -3.744460153500606, -6.745322900177551, -5.603888706985065, 2.1438507047870075, 2.0495595440342758, 2.11871084603453, 0.41288658666131856, -5.164230959789269, -4.008981956069332, 3.8680363668149886, -0.8370813876313971, 4.4863206398329405, 8.20037307724839, -3.868799732332584, 5.391752690754506, 0.2770880799495608, 2.5050243382196125, -0.486260285753729, 4.935030098266125, 5.192620665187931, 3.0052956261754056, -1.1261498758355368, 2.0533845916883027, -6.286581723628547, 0.2128092486147792, -1.1908918782071298, -3.1896458512857233, 6.737383626181149, 0.9855759091045054, -1.7691366839809188, -6.767659453904064, 0.39830286985262137, -0.5542511280316774, 3.710059825121781, 4.091527708825478, -2.353857205825426, 0.739699606300017, 5.933848613198472, 2.015693125629216, 3.1456919761476883, 0.09677657037249887, -4.724305854419665, -6.9008368126647195, -0.7418628090210766, 3.0897324090482354, 0.7325283416025677, 1.0562791586832845, 3.1222722204224373, 1.639399856868833, 1.13930669111732, -0.698264082691723, 1.6812425049344337, -2.726908403184771, 1.7821013938279193, 5.217874096442997, 1.5977085856403659, -1.5272064559938716, 2.578819896936208, -5.15025359190481, 2.161512575916617]

mass = 10
c = 20
k = 30
wn = np.sqrt(k/mass)
tc = 30
tau = 10
Ptau = yt[tau]

def g(tau):
    return ((Ptau)*np.sin(wn*(tc - tau)))
print(g)
temp = integrate.quad(g, 0, tc)
duh = (1/(mass*wn)) * temp
print (duh)
```

The result show "can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'numpy.float64'".
How can I fix it? Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a working reproducer? In your current example you haven't defined yt or mass and you haven't shown your imported modules (numpy and potentially scipy as well?).

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I have edited the code. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

`scipy.integrate.quad` returns a tuple of `(y, abserr)`, the integral and an estimate of the error in the integral. Assuming that you wanted to multiply by the integral I suggest you try tuple unpacking your `temp` variable.

```py
temp, _ = integrate.quad(g, 0, tc)
```